# routeProvider not picking up route AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, cakephp, routes

I would like to have my routes like Stack Overflow. So if I browse to `/category/id/` the server will redirect to `/category/id/name`. However I can't get the angularjs routing to pick up my routes when including slash.

So this is my secnarios:

```
localhost:81/butwhy => works    
localhost:81/category/id => redirects to localhost:81/category/fail    
localhost:81/category/id/name => redirects to localhost:81/category/id/fail
```

The routeProvider only seems to pick up the part after the last slash. Why?

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
        when('/category/:id/:name', {   
            templateUrl: '/view/example.html',
            controller: 'ExampleCtrl'
        }).
        when('/category/:id', {   
            templateUrl: '/view/example.html',
            controller: 'ExampleCtrl'
        }).
        when('/butwhy', {   
            // just for testing
        }).
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/view/examples.html',
            controller: 'ExamplesCtrl'
        }).     
        otherwise({ 
            redirectTo: 'fail'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

I don't know if it matters but I'm using CakePHP with WAMP and angularjs version 1.2.23

EDIT:

I have following in the /sitefolder/webroot .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And in the /sitefolder/ .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

The cakephp views is in /sitefolder/view/ and the html views for angular is in /sitefolder/webroot/view/

Comment: have you set up htaccess to work with html5mode? If not, you need to and if so somethings not right

Comment: Thank you charlietfl that is probably it. Atleast I know what to search for now

Comment: I changed my mind. I don't belive it is the htaccess since the routing works on the server and gives the layout back with the angularjs setup as it should. So why would id be? I tested several different htaccess configs yesterday though without success

Comment: did you put base tag in?

Comment: I have tried with base "http://localhost:81" and "/".

Comment: you must have base tag for html5 mode. Read the docs. I supsect you have Cake controllers competing with the SPA

Comment: I'm sorry but I have read the docs and I dont get it. What is SPA?
Before the route change to fail window.location.pathname is /category/id/name. I have tried with base "/category/" and "/category" also.

Comment: SPA= `Single Page App`.  Do you have Cake controllers/routes that match the ones you are using in angular?

Comment: Aha. How do they need to match? For now Im just using the Cake routing for ajax and the other routes just gets the default cake layout with an empty view. 
Its important for me to be able to change the layout later for some different pages that should have a different angular model and layout html. However I dont have to be able to use the views in cake since I got them in angularjs

Comment: I'm only asking because you don't want Cake controllers or routes to take over. But I think they are still conflicting somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never got it to work with cakephp serving the layout. However I found out that you can have nested views in ui-router. So I dont need to serve the layout through cakephp anymore.

With a regular index.html as layout in the webroot and all ajax calls through /ajax/name i setup the .htaccess like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^ajax index.php [NE,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [NE,L]
</IfModule>
```

But this didn't work when I browsed directly to localhost:81, then it used index.php instead of index.html. It worked when I hade a path in the url though.
The fix for this was to change the order in httpd.conf so index.html is before index.php

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.php3 index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing #, please try the following.

The URL should be

localhost:81/#/category/id  
localhost:81/#/category/id/name

Comment: html5mode removes the hashbang.